# Common Methods/Functions against two Classes - VB.NET

Tags: vb.net

I have a case as follows (VB.NET):

class A (contains some fields)
class B inherits List(Of A)

class C (contains some fields)
class D inherits List(Of C)

There are some common Methods and Functions that I want them to be centralized and act on both classes B & D, without the need to re-write them and keep them updated under both classes.

Those common Methods and Functions act on identical fields (name and type) in both classes A and C.

What should I do? And why to inherit from List(Of T) is considered a bad idea?

---

My solution was to create new Abstract (MustInherit) class X and moves the common fields from Classes A & C to class X. Then created a 'Friend' Module that has those common methods and functions (targeting the common fields between classes A & C) which takes IEnumerable(Of class X) .. and voila!

Any comments on such implementation??

---

Thanks

The below is my solution using IEnumerable, but using a shared function in a separate module.

```
Public MustInherit Class ProbSts 'class X
    Public Status As Boolean
    Public Probability, Min, Max As Integer
End Class

Public NotInheritable Class SIPRouteProbabilityStatus 'class A
    Inherits ProbSts
    Public Route As SIPRoute
End Class

Public NotInheritable Class SIPRGProbabilityStatus ' class C
    Inherits ProbSts
    Public RG As SIPRouteGroup
End Class

Public NotInheritable Class SIPRouteProbabilityStatusCollection ' class B
    Inherits List(Of SIPRouteProbabilityStatus)
    Public ProbabilityTotal As Integer

    Public Function TotalProbability(Optional Status As Boolean? = Nothing) As Integer
        Return TotalProbabilityAction(Me, Status)
    End Function

End Class

Public NotInheritable Class SIPRGProbabilityStatusCollection 'class D
    Inherits List(Of SIPRGProbabilityStatus)
    Public ProbabilityTotal As Integer

    Public Function TotalProbability(Optional Status As Boolean? = Nothing) As Integer
        Return TotalProbabilityAction(Me, Status)
    End Function
End Class


Friend Module ProbabilityAction

    Public Function TotalProbabilityAction(ProbStsList As IEnumerable(Of ProbSts), Optional Status As Boolean? = Nothing) As Integer
        Dim sum As Integer = 0
        For Each x In ProbStsList
            If Status.HasValue Then
                If x.Status = Status.Value Then sum += x.Probability
            Else
                sum += x.Probability
            End If
        Next
        Return sum
    End Function

End Module
```

Comment: Deriving from List(Of T) is not recommended because none of its members are virtual.  So you can't make it behave differently.  That was intentional, it is just a stock implementation of IList(Of T), designed to be as efficient as possible.  Encapsulation is the better strategy.  Do what works.

Comment: Hans, thanks. But in my code, I actually don't change the behavior of List(Of T), I rather add (extend) some functions and methods to run over its individual members, just to keep thins clean.

Example:
Class A
Public Status as Boolean
Public Probability as Integer
Public Route as SIPRoute 'this is a custom class
End Class

Class B
Inherits List(Of A)

'The below function will retrieve the first object (class A) in its members whose Status field is set to True
Public Function IsThereAnyActiveThing() as Boolean
Return FindIndex(Function(X) X.Status) > -1
End Function

End Class

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is nothing wrong with inheriting from `List(Of T)` when done properly. It's hard to give the best solution without seeing your classes and how you're using them, but your solution of inheriting from an abstract class is one way of solving it. However from your description, implementing an interface seems to be a better fit. Convert X to an interface with the common fields and you'll be good to go. The actual fields will stay in class A and C, yet the external functions will know how to access and use them.

What's the difference between using an interface vs. an abstract class in your case?

Interface: it only defines the common fields and methods of the classes and leaves the implementation to them.

Abstract Class: It actually hosts the common fields and methods with the implementation so the classes don't need to duplicate the code in case it is the same.

**EDIT** I don't know if this is the best solution, because I need to see how all these classes are used in your code, but you can get rid of the module by converting it to a class that inherits from `List(Of T)` and then inherit this class instead of `List(Of T)` in your `B` and `D` classes. Something like this:

```
Public MustInherit Class ProbSts 'class X
    Public Status As Boolean
    Public Probability, Min, Max As Integer
End Class

Public NotInheritable Class SIPRouteProbabilityStatus 'class A
    Inherits ProbSts

    Public Route As SIPRoute
End Class

Public NotInheritable Class SIPRGProbabilityStatus ' class C
    Inherits ProbSts

    Public RG As SIPRouteGroup
End Class

Public MustInherit Class ProbabilityAction(Of T)
    Inherits List(Of T)

    Public Function TotalProbabilityAction(ProbStsList As IEnumerable(Of ProbSts), Optional Status As Boolean? = Nothing) As Integer
        Dim sum As Integer = 0
        For Each x In ProbStsList
            If Status.HasValue Then
                If x.Status = Status.Value Then sum += x.Probability
            Else
                sum += x.Probability
            End If
        Next

        Return sum
    End Function
End Class

Public NotInheritable Class SIPRouteProbabilityStatusCollection ' class B
    Inherits ProbabilityAction(Of SIPRouteProbabilityStatus)

    Public ProbabilityTotal As Integer

    Public Function TotalProbability(Optional Status As Boolean? = Nothing) As Integer      
        Return TotalProbabilityAction(Me, Status)
    End Function
End Class

Public NotInheritable Class SIPRGProbabilityStatusCollection 'class D
    Inherits ProbabilityAction(Of SIPRGProbabilityStatus)

    Public ProbabilityTotal As Integer

    Public Function TotalProbability(Optional Status As Boolean? = Nothing) As Integer
        Return TotalProbabilityAction(Me, Status)
    End Function
End Class
```

I kept the original name of the module `ProbabilityAction`, but it's recommended to change it to a more suitable name for a base class. I also followed your way and qualified it with `MustInherit`, but you can decide if you want that or not.

Comment: I would just like to point out that a class doesn't inherit an interface. An interface can inherit another interface, i.e. extend its functionality, but a class implements an interface. I think that using the correct terminology is important because it reduces confusion.

Comment: @jmcilhinney I don't see any possible confusion there, but sure, edited it to use the correct terminology. Thanks for your note.

Comment: You don't see how calling a thing something that it's not could cause confusion? If someone is trying to learn what inheritance is and they are told that a class can inherit an interface then I don't see how that could possibly NOT lead to confusion. Even if that were not the case, I just don't see any reason to not use the correct terminology when doing so is not more difficult than using incorrect terminology.

Comment: @jmcilhinney Calm down, buddy. I didn't say there was any reason to not use the correct terminology, and I corrected it and said thanks for the note, didn't I? All what I was saying is that in this case it's not confusing, and no I don't agree with your point that it is confusing in this case. This isn't a justification from using the wrong terminology, and again thanks for the correction. But it's just a simple fact that there is only one possible relationship between a class and an interface regardless of what it is called.

Comment: Racil, if I use an Interface, I will need to duplicate the implementation of the common methods and functions to each class B & D.

The implementation is identical so why to use an Interface? Interface only helps when just the name and signature matter, though implementation varies between different objects implementing such an Interface.

I am not so happy with my solution, having to create such common methods and functions externally in a module.

Comment: @RacilHilan, the common 'things' between class A & C are primitive variables (Boolean and Integer), so there is no implementation required, that's why I used 'MustInherit' class holding just those common primitive fields.

Note that my requirement is to be able to call such common methods/functions on classes B & D, which inherit from List(Of A), List(Of C) respectively. That's why I build those as standalone in a 'Friend' module. Is there a better way to move them in some class? Or this this ok?

Comment: You say the common things are primitive variables and no implementation required, but then you say there are common methods. Is the code in those common methods the same? If yes, then they should be in the abstract class. If the code for those methods is different between the two classes, then it is likely that an interface is better. Again, it is hard to be sure without seeing your code for the classes and how they're used, so you can post the code in your question or at lease describe it in more details. Otherwise, just follow the comparison in my answer.

Comment: @RacilHilan, I've attached section of the code showing all the classes A, B, C and D with the module used to build the solution. Is there a way to get rid of the module?

Comment: Yes, you can get rid of the module. See my updated answer.

Comment: @RacilHilan .. Thanks. It's better now. I think no more can be done. Have a great day.